# How to get all selected checkbox from multiple pagination page in asp.net mvc?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Could someone please help me to understand how can i get all the checkbox were checked throughout all the pagination page?

using below seem only show the current page checkbox, not all pages.

Not sure if anything miss out, thanks for enlightenment!

```
$('input[name=myCheckbox]:checked');
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What kind of pagination you are talking about? An ajax one or a server-side one?

Comment: @Δάκης Ανδρέου, I use Ajax.Pager.

Comment: How would you expect to get the checkbox values if they don't exist on the page. You would need to store the values somewhere before moving to another page

Comment: @Wolf Apparently on every pagination swap, previous checkboxes are not kept in DOM but instead replaced by new ones. On every pagination swap you should save checked ones in a variable and so on.

Comment: I have stored checked checkboxs by using localStorage, but i don't know how to get value of these when i post to controller when i click a button

Comment: How are you posting back (AJAX or normal submit)? And what is the signature of the controller method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for

```
           <input type="checkbox" onchange="selectCheckbox(this)" />

 var selectedUnits = [];
                function selectCheckbox(data) {
                    if (selectedUnits.length < 1) {
                        selectedUnits.push(data.value);
                    }
                    else {
                        if (data.checked == true) {
                            if ($.inArray(data.value, selectedUnits) < 0) {
                                selectedUnits.push(data.value);
                            }
                            else {
                                selectedUnits.pop(data.value);
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            selectedUnits.pop(data.value);
                        }

                    }
                }
```

Comment: thank @Vivekh very much, but when i change page to page number 2, old checked checkboxs are disappeared.